# ISO File Bigger On The Outside Then On The Inside

Tags: iso-image

I have an ISO file that is ~7.6 GB on disk but when it's opened with 7-Zip or other ISO tools there's only about 12 MB of data available.

Outside:

[image]

Inside:

[image]

Is anyone aware of ISO files being able to be partitioned or know a way to access all of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO files are uncompressed.  That is to say, I suspect that the majority of that DVD image is full of zeroes.  You can confirm by opening the .iso file with a plaintext editor like Notepad++ .

The original question said "12 MB of data available" but it really meant "Only 12 MB of data present on the disk".

If you have reason to believe that there's data missing, I suggest contacting the person who made that ISO, to have them make another.